# iptables on boot - issue on update

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, bridge

I seem to have come across a strange issue that seems to have to with iptables, though I'm not entirely certain.

The machine is headless server running squid3, bind9, and other minor services. The issue popped up immediately following an upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04.1 to 16.04.2.

iptables rules, unchanged for many months, have always been applied on this machine in /etc/network/interfaces like so :

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug p4p1
iface p4p1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.254
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

allow-hotplug p5p1
iface p5p1 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

Following the update, though, when the pre-up line exists in the file, no internet connection (p5p1) works on boot. squid, which bridges p4p1 and p5p1 returns DNS errors. iptables -L -v prints out the rules correctly, with no rule having an unusually high rejection rate.

When the line is commented out, and the system is rebooted, everything works fine (with no firewall). If I then run iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules manually, the rules all get populated correctly and everything still works.

```
# iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source   destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere  anywhere            
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  !lo    any     anywhere  127.0.0.0/8 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    6   436 ACCEPT     all  --  p4p1   any     anywhere   anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  p5p1   any     anywhere   anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  p5p1   any     anywhere   anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:26
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  p5p1   any     anywhere   anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  p5p1   any     anywhere   anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:https
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere   anywhere state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere   anywhere limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere   anywhere reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source     destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  p4p1   any     192.168.1.54   anywhere            
    ... snip
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  p4p1   any     192.168.1.246  anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere       anywhere state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    60 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere       anywhere reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source      destination         
    5   600 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere         anywhere
```

The iptables.rules file I'm using is :

```
*filter 

-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

#
# Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and
# reject all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i !lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

#
# Accept everything from internal network
-A INPUT -i p4p1 -j ACCEPT

#
# Accept new connections only for ssh, http, and https
# from external network
-A INPUT -i p5p1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i p5p1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 26  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i p5p1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 80  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i p5p1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

#
# Accepts all established inbound traffics
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#
# Reject everything else
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j REJECT

#
#
# Packet forwarding
#

#
# Allow new connection forwarding from 192.168.1.xx
-A FORWARD -i p4p1 -s 192.168.1.54  -j ACCEPT
... snip ..
-A FORWARD -i p4p1 -s 192.168.1.246 -j ACCEPT 

#
# Allow forwarding of established connections
-A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#
# Reject everything else
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
#
# Network address translation
*nat

#
# Enable masquerade
-A POSTROUTING -o p5p1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Any insight into what may be going on would be much appreciated.